# Incompatibility of Bootstrap3 with JPlayer Circle Player

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jplayer

I'm trying to get JPlayer's nice looking Circle Player:
http://jplayer.org/latest/demos/
to work with Bootstrap3.  It works with Bootstrap 2.3.
There appears to be an incompatibility.  It sure would be great if anyone knows how to fix it, or could find it.  I think that this will probably affect others as well.
I haven't been able to find a solution online.

Here are some details:
1. Circle player works correctly when bootstrap is not loaded.
2. Circle player works correctly when the following is included:
//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css
3. Circle player does not display properly when the following is included:
//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css

Circle Player itself includes the following libraries: 
jquery.transform2d.js, jquery.grab.js, mod.csstransforms.min.js, circle.player.js

Using the following Bootstrap 3 theme:
https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/3-in-1-admin-front-end-e-commerce-WB0G69690

Comment: Can you post your code or recreate the problem on [Bootply](http://bootply.com)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just ran into this, and found that it's because Bootstrap 3 applies "box-style: border-box" with the universal selector * (See the [Release Notes](http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2013/08/19/bootstrap-3-released/)). Just apply "box-sizing: content-box;" to .cpContainer and it will look as expected.

Comment: For example, style="box-sizing: content-box;"

Comment: Thanks, a very helpful answer!